# in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

Rows consist of letters and numbers that had 6 strings expression. I want to    group these rows according to at least 3 strings be similar.

How can I do?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear. What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried? Have you tried using a query with a `Like statement`?

Answer (score 1):

Right click your field that you want to calculate values into, click Field Calculator. Select Python parser.

FieldName = !AAAA![:3]

Will bring the first 3 numbers/letters into your new field. Then dissolve on that field by the value. This should give you groups of your values. If that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this python field calculator function (make sure you enable the python parser):

```
def findValue(val):
  found = val.find('1A3')
  if found > -1:
    return val[:3]
  else: return '' # returns empty string if characters are not found
```

Here is the function call:

```
findValue(!myFieldToPerformFindOn!)
```